# Chrome driver information in console

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im using ChromeDriver in my selenium tests, in console Im getting:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (521791b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on port 15823
```

is there any way to skip or not show this at all in console output?

Comment: Getting messy when before every test its pop out in console. I would like to clean it for jenkins purpose, if its possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the chrome driver silent by setting [`webdriver.chrome.silentOutput`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.java#57) to `true`:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
```